# How to Select MAX Date, and then find sum after that date

Tags: sql, zoho

###### SUM is not giving correct amount when WHERE condition is NULL

```
SELECT
         DE."Donor First Name",
         DE."Donor Last Name",
         EX."SUM(Amount)",
         No."MAX(Note Written)",
         SUM(DE."Amount")
FROM  "Latest Thank You Note" AS  No
JOIN "Over 250 - Donors List" AS  EX ON No."Full Name"  = EX."Donor Name" 
JOIN "Donor Table" AS  DE ON No."Full name"  = DE."Full Name"  
WHERE    DE."Date"  >= No."MAX(Note Written)"
 OR No."Max(Note Written)"  Is NULL
GROUP BY 1,
     2,
     3,
      4
```

Here is the code I am writing. It pulls donors names, their total amount donated, then the last time they were written a thank you note, and what they've donated since. However, sometimes when I pull this table, if there was never a thank you note written "MAX(Note Written") is Null, then it will give me a random sum. Is there any way to fix it?

I Tried removing the null but it doesn't pull the correct results.

Comment: Could you please provide the sample data in your question?